# Retrieving gridview rows values using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi I have following grid view

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAll" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkEmployee" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCompany" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Company") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>              
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Than I am using following jquery code to iterate through the gridview for the selected check boxes and retrieve the values of columns for each row. Code will iterate through each row fine but cant pick the values.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#submit").click(function () {
               alert("clicked");
               $("#<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checked").each(function () {

               var values=$(this).find("td:Company")+$(this).find("td:Id");
               });
           });
       });
```

Following line is the one not working.

```
 var values=$(this).find("td:Company")+$(this).find("td:Id");
```

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made sample for you.

```
$('[type="button"]').live("click", function () {
  $('tr [type="checkbox"]:checked').parent().parent().each(function () {    
     if ($(this).find('input[id*="lblCompany"]').length > 0) {
   alert($(this).find('input[id*="lblCompany"]').val() + "---" +    $(this).find('input[id*="lblId"]').val())
}

});

 });
```

[**FIDDLE Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PgzrU/58/)

Hope it helps your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUserInfo" runat="server" >  
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />  
 <Columns>  
    <asp:TemplateField>  
    <ItemTemplate>  
             <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChild" runat="server" />  
           <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>  
            <asp:Label ID="lblCompany" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Company") %>'> </asp:Label>  
           <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Id") %>' />  
         <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCompany" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Company") %>' />  
       </ItemTemplate>  
    </asp:TemplateField>  
    </Columns>  
   </asp:GridView>  
   </div>  
    <input type="button" id="btnGet" value="Get Selected Values" /><br /><br />  
    <b>Select UserNames:</b><label id="lbltxt"/>


   <script type="text/javascript">      
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('#btnGet').click(function () {  
        var hdntxt = '';  
        $("input[name$=chkChild]:checked").each(function () {  
            hdntxt += "," + $(this).siblings("input[name$=lblId]").val()  
        });  
        $('#lbltxt').text(hdntxt.substring(1, hdntxt.length))  
    });  
});  
      </script>
```

Hope it will help